# gob encoding to/decoding from *os.File not working

Tags: go

When I use a file pointer `f *os.File` I get a empty map back

```
func decode(f *os.File, b map[string]interface{}) error {
    err := gob.NewDecoder(f).Decode(&b)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", b)
    return err
}

func encode(f *os.File, b map[string]interface{}) error {
    bb := map[string]interface{}{
        "X":        1,
        "Greeting": "hello",
    }
    err := gob.NewEncoder(f).Encode(bb)
    f.Sync()
    //fmt.Println(buf.Bytes())
    return err
}
```

prints `map[]`

If I replace it with a global buffer pointer `buf *bytes.Buffer` it works

```
func decode(f *os.File, b map[string]interface{}) error {
    err := gob.NewDecoder(buf).Decode(&b)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", b)
    return err
}

func encode(f *os.File, b map[string]interface{}) error {
    bb := map[string]interface{}{
        "X":        1,
        "Greeting": "hello",
    }
    err := gob.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(bb)
    return err
}
```

prints `map[Greeting:hello X:1]`

f is opened in main like this

```
var (
    buf      *bytes.Buffer
    f       *os.File
    memcache map[string]interface{}        
)

func main() {
    var err error
    f, err = os.Create("_memcache.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
    }
    defer f.Close() 

    memcache = make(map[string]interface{})
    buf = new(bytes.Buffer)
    gob.Register(map[string]interface{}{})
    err = write()
    if err != nil {
       log.Print(err.Error())
    }
    err = read()
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
    }
}

func read() (err error) {
    err = decode(f, memcache)
    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        return err
    }
}

func write() (err error) {
    err = encode(f, memcache)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
 }
```

Comment: Who ever was editing we where editing at the same time sorry :)

Comment: In your example, you do not show where encode and decode are called. Please note os.Create creates a new file, and truncates it if it already exists. You need to create the file, encode to it, close it, open it again (but not with os.Create) and decode from it.

Comment: Ok you are probably right here let me try to edit the code

Comment: done that is about it I think

Comment: Yeah, like @Didier said, to decode, you need to `Open` the file or `f.Seek(0, 0)` to read it from the start. In this respect files work differently from buffers.

Comment: Confirmed `f.Seek(0, 0)` is working, I don't think I would have figured that out myself :) please make answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is already mentioned in the comments, so the update method `main()` is following:

```
func main() {
    var err error
    f, err = os.Create("_memcache.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
    }
    defer f.Close()

    memcache = make(map[string]interface{})
    buf = new(bytes.Buffer)
    gob.Register(map[string]interface{}{})

    err = write()
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
    }

    // after write the file pointer is at the end of the file,
    // so it should be moved:      
    f.Seek(0, 0)

    // alternatively, open the file in read()
    err = read()
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
    }
}
```